# Adding a class to an element within a string

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to add a class to the form element within the string. Is there an easy way to do this without jQuery?

```
var foo = '<form class="overlay"><div></div></form>';
foo.classList.add('bar');
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: **`foo` is string**.

Comment: You can use regex: `foo = foo.replace(/class="(.*?)"/, function(m, $1) {
        return 'class="' + $1 + ' bar"';
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to convert `foo` to a DOM element by using an inmemory `div`. Then you can convert it back to string with `innerHTML` after adding the expected `class`. By the way, it's not recommended to manipulate HTML string with regex or any other string manipulation methods.

```js
var foo = '<form class="overlay"><div></div></form>';
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = foo;
div.querySelector('form').classList.add('bar');
alert(div.innerHTML);
```